# delete a record (client only) in JTable using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-jtable

I'm using JTable and JQuery for an html page, adding the records manually in JTable using `jtable addRecord` option. I want to delete the added record based on user selection locally i.e., on client side only. Hence, I use the below code, the record contains TeamName & TeamDescription.

```
$.fn.deleteTeamRow = function() {
            var $selectedRows = $('#TeamContainer').jtable('selectedRows');
            $selectedRows.each(function () {
                var record = $(this).data('record');
                var teamname = record.TeamName;
                $('#TeamContainer').jtable('deleteRecord', {
                    key: teamname,
                    clientOnly: true,
                    success: (function() {
                        alert("record deleted");
                    }),
                    error: (function() {
                        alert("record deletion error!");
                    })
                });
            });
        };
```

Unable to either get the success or error alert.

Kindly, let me know how to delete a record on client side only.

Comment: Is this Question related to Java Swing?

Comment: No i have not used Java Swing nor Java, only html and javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue the 'key' was missed while defining the columns in the Table.

```
    $('#TeamContainer').jtable({
            selecting: true,
            columnResizable: false,
            selecting: true, //Enable selecting
            multiselect: true, //Allow multiple selecting
            selectingCheckboxes: true,
            actions: {
            },
            fields: {
                TeamName: {
                    title: 'Team Name',
                    **key: true,**
                    sorting: true
                },
                TeamDescription: {
                    title: 'Team Description',
                    create: false
                }
            }
        });
```